How to Disable Notifications for Local Technician During Holidays in GLPI?
I need some help with managing notifications in GLPI. One of our local technicians is going on holiday, and I'd like to disable all notifications for him during this period. I want to make sure he doesn't receive any alerts or emails from GLPI while he's away.
Could anyone guide me on how to do this? Is there a specific setting in GLPI for handling such cases, or do I need to manually adjust some configurations? Any detailed steps or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
